# Branching for releases, features, sub-features and environments

Tags: tfs, merge, branch

I have gone through the TFS rangers guides before posting this.

I have the below requirement in our project:

1. Development of release 1 happens
2. It is deployed on Dev environment for integration and sanity test
3. If ok, then the code is deployed on QA environment
4. If ok, QA released code gets deployed on production.

Currently we have a code base in TFS under CODE, where developers code.
The above is branched to DEV to mirror dev environment code
DEV branch is branched to QA branch

In case a hot fix is required, then it is fixed directly on QA branch, and then later reverse merged to below branches.

This was fine till first time development, but I feel this needs to be re-structured to be better scalable for future release development.

Current issues:

1. need to plan to support future release 1.5 development
2. At the moment there are some features/fixes which may/may not go in
   current release. Developers just shelf it at the moment so that they
   can be unshelved in future. Issue is that with time, shelves become
   huge pain to merge as they do not have history
3. Sometime people work on big features on shelves for upto a week.
   Merging becomes a huge paint as till then those dozens of files have
   also been worked by a lot of people.

Keeping all the above in mind, i am thinking of redesigning our TS branching stategy as depicted below:

[image: Branching to support features and releases]

As per this approach:

- Development would happen on a dev branch such as DevRel1 branch only
- If a developer needs to work on a big feature, he would work on a
  branch such as Feature 1 branch, branched from Dev branch. On
  completion he would merge back to dev branch.
- For probably features, which may or may not go in this release, the
  develop needs to work on probably feature branched from main branch. 
  As per final decision, it would be base less merged into appropriate 
  dev branch.
- Code would be deployed in Dev environment from Dev branch
- Code would be deployed to QA branch from Main
- For release, main would be branched to a new release branch
- Hot fixes on QA happen on Main branch, and on Release happen on
  release branch. RI from release happens to main, and FI to dev
  branches happen in this case

Is this getting too complex? can it be simplified, does this look fine process wise, or does it need correction?

We are using TFS 2008 at the moment.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is specific enough for [so]. It might do better on [programmers.se], but might be too loose for them as well. Also, which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: I haven't read all of your question, but I looked over that diagram. You do know that TFS won't allow you to merge unrelated branches right? I mean, if you take branch X from branch Y, and then later take branch Z, also from branch Y, TFS will not let you merge from X to Y. The common branch is Z, so everything has to go through that one. It seems that topmost branch there is going across branches.

Comment: Lasse, won't baseless merge work here? I have shown in my diagram this as BM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to keep things as simple as you can. IMHO the main things to avoid are:

- Complexity confuses people. The more complexity there is, the more time it takes to deal with, the more merges you end up doing, and the more mistakes that are made. If you don't *need* a process then remove it.
- If you work on code in a branch, then you will necessarily need to merge code in the future. The longer branches live before they are merged the more difficult and time consuming the merge becomes.
- "Piggybacking" a hierarchy of branches on each other introduces the need to merge through multiple levels to get code back to the dev branch, which makes it time consuming to push a change from an outlying branch back into the main codebase.

So you should definitely use branching to support your dev needs, but try to keep your scheme as simple as possible.

We use a similar, but simpler, approach to yours. That is:

- We work on a Dev branch. Daily builds come off this branch for continuous QA.
- When a release "code freeze" is required, a Release branch is made. A bugfix can be made in either branch, but if required for the release it is always immediately merged to keep dev & release in sync. We try not to let releases diverge from the main branch at all if possible. We never have more than one release branch active at a time.
- When small features are developed, or where features can be developed without becoming "enabled" in the application or otherwise affecting the stability of the code, we continue to develop the code within the Dev branch. E.g We might use an #if condition to disable the code until it is safe to "activate" in daily test builds. This minimises the need for branching.
- When a large feature is developed that could potentially break the Dev branch, we work on a separate Feature branch. We try to plan the feature to minimise the time during which the feature/dev branches are allowed to coexist, and if possible stop developers working on related areas of the code while the feature is developed, to minimise the merge problems when the feature completes. If possible features are developed between releases to minimise the overlap (the number of concurrent branches).

Our other key strategies are:

- Use Continuous Integration, Unit Tests, Regression Tests, Gated Checkins and continuous QA testing to keep the Dev branch as stable as possible. Our aim is that any daily build "should" be good enough to ship straight to a customer. In reality there are occasional short periods (a few days) where that stability is lost, but most of the time when these happen we are still within a few days of having a releasable build.
- Defer making branches until absolutely needed. In TFS you can retroactively create a branch from any point in the codebase history. So when we are ready to start a release branch, we don't actually create the branch but just send the current release build to the QA department for testing. If they are happy with the quality of that build, it goes to customers as is, with no branch having been created. It is only *when* we need to fix a bug for that release that we actually create the branch (from the point in time where the original release-candidate was built, so we know it starts from the well tested code snapshot) and incur the (small) costs that entails.

As a side note, we also tried a Dev branch, with gated checkins to QA branch with gated checkins to Release branch, but this worked poorly (Primarily we found that it added a considerable overhead to all development. We like to check in frequently and the two extra test-and merge steps for every checkin are expensive. In the worst cases, if you delete, move or rename files in TFS it becomes very flakey and even simple merges fail - these are difficult and time consuming to sort out. We decided that merging in TFS is still not lightweight and robust enough to support this sort of approach unless you are prepared to invest a lot of time into managing the branches. On the other hand, if devs are careful with their checkins, there is far less need for such a "rigorous" approach. So we swapped back to the above lightweight approach, which increases the risks but minimises the need to merge - for us (with a smallish and disciplined/competent team) this approach works better.

Comment: So if i understand your current approach correctly, you do have a main trunk, and from that you have a branch of Dev on which your major development happens. You send code from Dev to QA too. One query here is that your release branch is made from Main or Dev? Feature branches are branched from Dev or Main?

Comment: There is usually only one branch (which we call Dev, but this is the Main branch if you like). We all work in it, and daily builds from it are tested by QA. When ready to stabilise a release, we create a temporary release branch. All bug fixes for the release are merged immediately back into Dev, so as soon as the release occurs, the release branch is abandonded. When working on a big feature, we create a feature branch and merge it back when it's complete. But 90%-95% of the time we only have one branch, Dev.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all your responses. I have hence simplified my design and we plan to tweak it a bit before doing a test run on it.

The new design is as shown below(comments on it are still always welcome!)

[image: Updated branching design]

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents ...

For correctness, I would suggest to have the **PossibleFeature1** branch merge back to the same branch it originates from, so the main. Talking about which, do not differentiate between a **Feature** and a **PossibleFeature** branch. They are the same. Features are alway subject to delay, reprioritization, whatever reason why they won't end up in the planned release. Allow this flexibility in principle for every Feature branch. So treat every Feature the same.

To further simplify your model (and your life) think about only having a **main** branch for development and QA. The additional overhead and complexity of having both is not worth the effort. Deploy stable main versions to QA from the main development line. Label the shipped versions.

So my (personal) model would be to have a main development branch. Big challenging features are put on their own branch. They might end up in the release, they might go to the next, no worries. Keep merging from the main into the feature branches on a regular basis to keep them in sync. It is good to have seperate Release branches if you have multiple versions out in the field that you need to support for a while. Start the Release branch before your stabilization, alpha and beta stages. You might consider deployment to QA as part of these Release branches.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and pointer. I see your point that I should treat features and possible feature branch as same. You mention that Is should avoid having seperate branches for QA and DEV. As per my diagram I do not have a seperate branch for QA, becuase I was planning to treat main/trunck as QA. Reason is that sometimes we have features which are testing/stabilizing on the dev environment, bt do not want it to go to QA yet. So I was thinking in lines of mergeing from Dev to Main only when we know it needs to be released.

Comment: Also, by this diagram I was planning for a structure where dev branch has daily changing code. So we would deploy to Dev environment from Dev branch, and if OK, it would be merged to Main, so that we can deploy to QA from Main. If this is OK, then should features be branching and merging back to from Dev or Main? If I do from Main, then on mergign bakc, they will have bypassed the Dev testing when dev is deployed to dev environment

Comment: Branch features from dev and merge back to dev again, so you don't bypass you dev testing stage. But, just another consideration, what about not having a dev next to main at all? Why not use main for your dev?

Comment: Because all the best practices I read, including rangers, seem to suggest that we should never ever code primarily on main. Not sure if i interpreted it in-correctly.

Comment: I have never done otherwise, over the past 10 years. How big is your team of developers?

Comment: Then, again my personal opinion is that it is fine to use your main branch for development. Just split off risky features in their own branch. This is also proposed in the comment of Jason.